# Library database search with multiple JOINs is too slow

Tags: performance, sql, mysql, join

I have a MySQL query which runs very slowly. I've rewritten it many times but no improvements yet.

My current query for advanced search takes about 60 secs to complete. Any suggestions for improving this?

- Database: MySQL
- Webserver: Apache - PHP (PDO)

Current code structure:

```
SELECT  B.title, COUNT(*) AS NUM 
FROM library.PhysicalInfo A 
LEFT JOIN library.BibliographicInfo B 
    ON A.BookID = B.BibliographicInfoID 
LEFT JOIN library.authors C 
    ON B.BibliographicInfoID = C.BookID 
LEFT JOIN library.BookAuthors D 
    ON C.BookAuthorID = D.PersonID 
LEFT JOIN library.series E 
    ON B.BibliographicInfoID = E.BookID 
LEFT JOIN library.BooksLocation F 
    ON A.location = F.BookLocationID 
LEFT JOIN library.PublishStatement G 
    ON B.BibliographicInfoId=G.BookID 
LEFT JOIN library.publisher H 
    ON G.PublisherID = H.PublisherID 
WHERE (     B.title  LIKE '%سلام%' OR 
            D.name LIKE '%سلام%' OR 
            F.location LIKE '%سلام%' OR 
            G.place  LIKE '%سلام%' OR 
            G.year LIKE '%سلام%' OR 
            H.name LIKE '%سلام%' ) 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

I've created indexes for all the fields which are used in join comparisons and `WHERE` statements:

```
CREATE INDEX PersonID ON library.BookAuthors(PersonID);
....
```

My table structures are:

> ```
> mysql> DESCRIBE PhysicalInfo;
>
> +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
> +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | PhysicalInfoID | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
> | volume         | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
> | section        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
> | year           | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
> | RegisterNo     | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
> | barcode        | varchar(45)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
> | location       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
> | BookID         | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
> | version        | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
> +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
>
> mysql> DESCRIBE BibliographicInfo;
>
> +------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | Field                  | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
> +------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | BibliographicInfoID    | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
> | LCNO                   | varchar(45)   | YES  |     | NULL    | |
> | DeviNo                 | varchar(45)   | YES  |     | NULL    | |
> | title                  | varchar(200)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    | |
> | ISBN                   | varchar(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    | |
> | language               | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    | |
> | IsReference            | smallint(6)   | YES  |     | NULL    | |
> +------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> ```

`EXPLAIN EXTENDED` result:

> ```
> *************************** 1. row ***************************
>            id: 1
>   select_type: SIMPLE
>         table: A
>          type: ALL
> possible_keys: NULL
>           key: NULL
>       key_len: NULL
>           ref: NULL
>          rows: 348390
>      filtered: 100.00
>         Extra: NULL
> *************************** 2. row ***************************
>            id: 1
>   select_type: SIMPLE
>         table: B
>          type: eq_ref
> possible_keys: PRIMARY,BibliographicInfoID
>           key: PRIMARY
>       key_len: 4
>           ref: library.A.BookID
>          rows: 1
>      filtered: 100.00
>         Extra: NULL
> *************************** 3. row ***************************
>            id: 1
>   select_type: SIMPLE
>         table: C
>          type: ref
> possible_keys: BookID_idx,BookID
>           key: BookID_idx
>       key_len: 5
>           ref: library.B.BibliographicInfoID
>          rows: 1
>      filtered: 100.00
>         Extra: NULL
> *************************** 4. row ***************************
>            id: 1
>   select_type: SIMPLE
>         table: D
>          type: eq_ref
> possible_keys: PRIMARY,PersonID
>           key: PRIMARY
>       key_len: 4
>           ref: library.C.BookAuthorID
>          rows: 1
>      filtered: 100.00
>         Extra: NULL
> *************************** 5. row ***************************
>            id: 1
>   select_type: SIMPLE
>         table: E
>          type: ref
> possible_keys: BookID
>           key: BookID
>       key_len: 5
>           ref: library.B.BibliographicInfoID
>          rows: 2
>      filtered: 100.00
>         Extra: Using index
> *************************** 6. row ***************************
>            id: 1
>   select_type: SIMPLE
>         table: F
>          type: eq_ref
> possible_keys: PRIMARY,BookLocationID
>           key: PRIMARY
>       key_len: 4
>           ref: library.A.location
>          rows: 1
>      filtered: 100.00
>         Extra: NULL
> *************************** 7. row ***************************
>            id: 1
>   select_type: SIMPLE
>         table: G
>          type: ref
> possible_keys: book_idx,BookID
>           key: book_idx
>       key_len: 5
>           ref: library.B.BibliographicInfoID
>          rows: 1
>      filtered: 100.00
>         Extra: NULL
> *************************** 8. row ***************************
>            id: 1
>   select_type: SIMPLE
>         table: H
>          type: eq_ref
> possible_keys: PRIMARY,PublisherID
>           key: PRIMARY
>       key_len: 4
>           ref: library.G.PublisherID
>          rows: 1
>      filtered: 100.00
>         Extra: Using where
> 8 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
> ```

My current query (on about 5 million records) takes 60 secs!

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For 5 million records...using `LIKE`...?  60 seconds doesn't sound all that outrageous.

Comment: I don't think indexes can help you much when you're doing `LIKE '%something%'`. Do you really need such searches? If `LIKE 'something%'` is enough that *might* help. It would be best eliminate all the `LIKE` if you can.

Comment: Thanks for including some schema and `EXPLAIN` information with your question.

Comment: @cHao: But current search engine (based on SQL Server 2000) does that in a few seconds (might be even lower since I'm looking from the client side). In a book search panel, this is outrageous :(

Comment: @janos: Yes, exactly, using a wildcard in the start of a string would cause all indexes on that column to become unuseful. But it doesn't seem to be any other way to implement a simple search box for users. (I obviously cannot ask them to enter the first few characters of their desired book :) )

Comment: @200_success: thank you for seeing my question :) just following the community rules :)

Comment: [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back Rev 4 → 3.

Comment: @200_success: Sorry for that /  How should I change it so that new visitor won't misunderstand it?

Comment: The issue has been mentioned in an answer. That should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than address performance, I'd first like to raise some skepticism about the correctness of the query.

I don't think that `PhysicalInfo A LEFT JOIN BibliographicInfo` is appropriate.  What that `LEFT JOIN` means is that it's OK to include a `PhysicalInfo` record that has no corresponding `BibliographicInfo` record.  It is therefore possible for a selected `BibliographicInfo.title` to be `NULL`.

I'm also puzzled by `COUNT(*)`.  What exactly is it that you are trying to count?  The number of `BookAuthors` times the number of `BooksLocation`s times the number of `Publisher`s times the number of `Series` that each book title appears in (except that each zero counts as a factor of one)?  I'm not even sure that such a count has a reasonable practical interpretation.  Furthermore, you used an aggregate function `COUNT(*)` without any `GROUP BY`, which is forbidden in standard SQL.  (MySQL is unreasonably lenient about these broken queries unless you configure the server to be strict, using [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).)

Comment: I AM TERRIBLY Sorry! The "GROUP BY" was unintentionally deleted while I was formatting my question. Anyhow, The "SELECT" part doesn't seem to have much effect on speed. I used SELECT * / SELECT 'col_name' / , etc. "GROUP BY" is because I want to group my search results by title and COUNT(*) to give me the number of books in that title (It actually works fine, but slow)

Comment: But it _doesn't_ give you the number of books with that title. What happens if a book has multiple authors?

Comment: It's a tough question... I think you're right and there's a call for a DISTINCT somewhere (maybe on bookIDs). I hate logical micro flaws in queries... thanks for noting

Comment: No. Using `DISTINCT` to deduplicate is inefficient and should be avoided. Instead, formulate your `JOIN`s to produce the correct number of rows. (Don't `JOIN` if what you really mean is `… WHERE EXISTS (SELECT …)`).

Comment: I think this would improve the query speed. I'm going to rewrite my query to test this.